# Android- Help fixing Custom Alert Dialog with EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, customdialog

*Context*: There is a custom Listview and each list item has a button in it. When you click the button an alertDialog appears with an edit text and submit button. This only happens on the first click, on subsequent clicks a Toast will simply appear with the number of times it has been clicked thus far.

When you click the submit button a toast will appear displaying the text that was entered into the editText and the number of times they have clicked on it which will presumably always be 1 since this can only happen on the first click.

*Problem*:  The timesClicked counter is not working properly if the user so much as clicks on the editText before clicking submit. It is restting to 0 I guess. However if the user does *not* click on the editText then the program works normally. 0_o I'm at a loss.

*Attempts at solving*: I simplified the code down quite a bit to try and pinpoint the problem and this is where I am stuck. Originally I was inflating a view that only had an edit text and then I was just using builder.setPositiveButtton. I thought implementing the buttons directly in the view would fix it but that doesn't seem to be the case. I have been stuck on this for awhile. Any help would be great

[Here is a video of the bug happening](https://youtu.be/qJRkwlil4MQ)

```
 private class OnSubtractClickListener implements View.OnClickListener  {

    final int id;  //id of list item that was clicked
    int timesClicked;
    Toast toast;

    public OnSubtractClickListener(int id, View view) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        timesClicked = 0;
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (timesClicked != 0) {
             toast.setText(Integer.toString(timesClicked));
             toast.show();
        }
        else{
            toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            final View dialogView =  LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_notes, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            builder.setView(dialogView);
            builder.setTitle("Subtract cigar?");
            builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.monkey_launcher);
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

            Button yesButton = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_notes_yes_button);
            yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText editText = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_editText);
                    String userInput = editText.getText().toString();
                    String timesClickedString = Integer.toString(++timesClicked);
                    toast.setText(timesClickedString + ": " + userInput);
                    toast.show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show(); //new
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order for times clicked to go back to 0, you must be recreating the click listener somewhere. Can you show where you're setting the click listener in your code?

Comment: It's only being reset when the user clicks on the editText in the dialog though. Otherwise it works fine. Im setting it in a bindView for customlistAdapter

Comment: Nobody knows the problem? In my app the database is being called and the listview is being updated. But then the listview actually reverts back to its previous state. However the database has been updated. Makes no sense. Is there anything that could cancel a change to a listview item

Comment: When do you create an instance of `OnSubtractClickListener `?

Comment: In the bind view of the custom cursor adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can make class that extend Dialog.

example:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog { 
  private EditText editText;        

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lpWindow = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lpWindow.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    lpWindow.dimAmount = 0.8f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lpWindow);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_dialog); 
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);        
  }  
}
```

You can use this dialog..

```
mCustomDialog = new CustomDialog();
mCustomDialog.show();
```

You can make the layout as you wish.

======================================================================

You can use AlertDialog.Builder.setPositiveButton.

site : [setPositiveButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton(int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))

example...

```
 toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 final View dialogView =  LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_notes, null);
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.setTitle("Subtract cigar?");
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.monkey_launcher);
        builder.setPositiveButton("text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                EditText editText = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_editText);
                String userInput = editText.getText().toString();
                String timesClickedString = Integer.toString(++timesClicked);
                toast.setText(timesClickedString + ": " + userInput);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show(); //new
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but this isn't what I was looking for. I'm not having an issue creating an editText inside the dialog. That part is easy. My issue is that when the user clicks on the editText and the virtual keyboard appears. What ever change is made to the listView after the dialog closes. Is reset.

Comment: Again thanks for trying but the issue isn't creating a dialog with an editText. I found out what the problem was and came up with a solution that I will post later tonight. Basically what was happening was that when the Keyboard appeared it would cause the listview to adjust the size recreating the whole listview with reycycled/old versions of the list items from before the dialog appeared -effectively undoing any changes made to the ListView items by the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Basically what was happening was that when the Keyboard appeared it would cause the listview to adjust the size recreating the whole listview with recycled/old versions of the list items from before the dialog appeared -effectively undoing any changes made to the ListView items by the dialog.

In your listview XML add this:

android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"

In Mainfest.xml:

```
<activity android:name= ".yourActivity"      
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```